# Prove that in a field F, reciprocals are unique. Namely, show that if x is a nonzero element of F, and $x · r_1 = x ·r_2 = 1,$ then $r_1 = r_2.$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I just needed some clarification on this question. How would I start? What are r_1 and r_2? Are they elements of f? Any help would be greatly appreciated
Prove that in a field F, reciprocals are unique. Namely, show that if x is a nonzero element of F,
and $x · r_1  = x · r_2  = 1,$ then $r_1  = r_2.  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axioms for a field state that multiplication is commutative and associative.

If $xr_1=1$ then $r_1x=1$..... So $xr_1=1=xr_2$ implies $$ r_1=r_1\cdot 1=r_1(xr_2)=(r_1x)r_2=1\cdot r_2=r_2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$(r_1x)r_2=r_2=r_1(xr_2)=r_1$. Since the multiplication is commutative $xr_2=r_2x=1$.

Comment: But what do $r_1$ and $r_2$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

The excellent answer of @DanielWainfleet works in any group such as the multiplicative group of the field in question. But here’s another proof, which uses the fact that the field is a ring without zero-divisors:

Take the putative two inverses of $x$, $r_1$ and $r_2$, so that $r_1x=r_2x=1$, and consequently $(r_1-r_2)x=0$ But since $x\ne0$, it must be that $r_1-r_2=0$.